# Regedit - Where can I get the pastable path back?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, regedit

I needed to downgrade my laptop to 1 version older windows, because of driver compatibility issues.

On my Desktop & the prereset Laptop, I had a bar for regedit, where you could paste the path. I feel like I had it from the beginning of Windows 10.
It looks like this: [image: PerferctPasta]

But my laptop doesn't have it, but it instead has it below and you can't paste there: [image: Laptop_Downgraded]

Is there a way to get my pastable path back? I tweak the registry quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a way to get my pasteable path back?

Another option is to install [RegAlyzer](https://www.safer-networking.org/products/regalyzer/) from Safer Networking:

> RegAlyzer is a tool to browse and change the registry. It was created because of a few features we missed in the original regedit tool, from support for exotic value types over background and regular expression search to better bookmarks, displaying .reg files in the accustomed style and a history view.

It has a location bar where you can paste the path:

[image]

The "Bookmarks" feature is also useful if you do a lot a registry edits to the same set of places, as is the "Search" feature, which supports regular expressions:

> [image]
>
> Functionality:
>
> A short list of the pros of RegAlyzer:
>
> - New: Undo and Redo logs in .reg format
> - Improved search function (results list)
> - Hierarchical bookmark support
> - Jump to key by command line parameter
> - Jump to key by typing/copying it into dialog (instead of browsing)
> - DWord editing with parallel hex/decimal/binary display
> - Support of QWord (64 bit integer)
> - Display of .reg file contents without importing it
> - Support of version 5 files (Unicode) even with Windows 95/NT
> - Low-level display of security settings with option to export it

Source [RegAlyzer](https://www.safer-networking.org/products/regalyzer/)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with Safer Networking in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

Comment: @KristoferVesi It works exactly like regedit with some new features added.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't @DavidPostill because I need to put My Computer/ in the front of my pastes & It somehow doesn't detect some paths...

Comment: @KristoferVesi No you don't. If you paste, for example, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.123\OpenWithProgIDs` and press return it will add  ``My Computer\`` to the front for you and jump to the matching key.

Comment: welp it doesn't open :/

Comment: welp now opens, on 2nd reinstall

Answer (score 2):

As magicandre1981 said, this is a [new feature of the Windows 10 Creators Update 1703](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-use-new-address-bar-registry-editor-windows-10).

Updating your Windows back to Version 1703 is the ideal option. If you don't want to do so, you can download an ISO, extract `sources\install.wim` and extract `Windows\regedit.exe` **from the WIM file** ([7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) can extract WIM). Then you can use the extracted Registry Editor and the address bar is back.

Comment: I have an USB with the install thing, didn't find it there, I'll download the ISO, so I can get it there, will keep updated

Comment: If you have that USB you can find `install.wim`. Extract it using [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) and get the newer `regedit.exe` build.

Comment: was able to get into install.esd with 7zip, it had dirs: 1,2,3,4,[deleted] everyone has windows and regedit.exe, but when I extract it & open, it gives UAC and then does nothing

Comment: Interesting. I extracted install.esd, from the folder 1 I ran regedit, it works, but as soon as it is out of the folder, it doesn't work anymore... So it kind of works, I will do some deleting files, to see what it needs and schortcut usage, thx for the answer

Comment: You can try putting it inside `C:\Windows`. Be sure not to replace the original one shipped with the system.

Comment: yeah, tried it long time ago, but it didn't work... Since the file is 30GB and my laptop has 128GB SSD, then sadness... I am now trying to delete other files from ti

Comment: managed to get it down to 18GB, down to 5GB would be the "worth it line" There isn't 1 big file there is just loads of files in folders, deleting the folder will make the regedit thing not work...

Comment: got the regalyzer working on 2nd install... 18GB just doesn't do it for me tx for trying still

Answer (score 1):

This is a [new feature of the Windows 10 Creators Update 1703](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-use-new-address-bar-registry-editor-windows-10). So update the Laptop back to Build 15063.

Comment: Sorry I am not, because as I said, driver issues (touchpad, pointstick, audio not working and others...)